# IOS resize the UILabel width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

How to resize the UIlabel width in IOS?
I have define

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

in viewcontroller.h.

and below is the code from view controller.m

```
    - (IBAction)btn_click:(id)sender {
         self.label.text = @"TEXT";
         self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
         self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         self.label.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,300,25);
         [self.label sizeToFit];

         [self.view addSubview:self.label];
    }
```

everything work fine except the UILabel width.
How to resize UIlabel width?

Thank You

Comment: change the frame.size.width and remove sizeToFit

Comment: Did you try changing `CGRectMake(50,50,300,25);` ? Here `300` is the width.

Comment: and you don't need to add the label again, just resize it, remove [self.view addSubview:self.label], i assume that you allready have the label in the storyboard.

Comment: Just remove autolayout property from the storyboard/xib.  It'll work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `xib` and make sure that `Autolayout` is unchecked or adjust the constraints.

Then, remove the `[self.label sizeToFit]` and `[self.view addSubview:self.label]` code.

```
- (IBAction)btn_click:(id)sender 
{
         self.label.text = @"TEXT";
         self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
         self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         self.label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 400, 25); //modified width is 400.
         //[self.label sizeToFit]; //remove this line

         //[self.view addSubview:self.label]; //do not add label again to your view
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

and if you want a nice animation you can add it in the UIView animation block, just like this:

```
- (IBAction)btn_click:(id)sender  
{
     self.label.text = @"TEXT";
     self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
     self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.33f animations:^{
    self.label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 25);

}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just se the UILabel frame,

```
 self.label.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,300,25);
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's doc:

> [sizeToFit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit)
>
> Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.

So you resize the label manually with `self.label.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,300,25);`, and then tell it to resize to fit its subview.

Remove the `sizeToFit` call, and you label should resize to the `CGRect` you passed.

Also, as Bogdan said in the comments, you should not add the label to its parent view when the label is created in Interface Builder (storyboard or xib).
This:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.label]
```

is useless and could produce weird results.